# Python: How to reorganize data with node, parent, sibling

Tags: python, dataframe, data-structures, tree

I have a data structure in a dataframe with 3 columns : node, parent, previous_sibling

I would like to create the tree folder of the full datastructure, with different level between parent and node, same level between node and previous_sibling, and in the right order between siblings.

As a result, a new dataframe, reordered, and a new column 'level'

When parent is null, the node is at root level
When previous_sibling is null, this is the first sibling

here is an example:

DATAFRAME

| node | parent | previous_sibling |
| --- | --- | --- |
| node0 |  |  |
| node1 |  | node2 |
| node2 |  | node0 |
| node3 | node2 |  |
| node4 | node1 | node7 |
| node5 | node2 | node6 |
| node6 | node2 | node3 |
| node7 | node1 |  |
| node8 | node6 |  |

should give the following DATAFRAME

| node | parent | previous_sibling | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| node0 |  |  | 0 |
| node2 |  | node0 | 0 |
| node3 | node2 |  | 1 |
| node6 | node2 | node3 | 1 |
| node8 | node6 |  | 2 |
| node5 | node2 | node6 | 1 |
| node1 |  | node2 | 0 |
| node7 | node1 |  | 1 |
| node4 | node1 | node7 | 1 |

This is what i have done until now, but it doesn't include the order of siblings

```
def getDescendants(curr, par, level):
    res = [[curr, par, level]]
    children = json_dataframe_flat.query('parent == @curr')
    for n in children.node:
        if n != par:
            deeper = getDescendants(n, curr, level + 1)
            if len(deeper) > 0:
                res.extend(deeper)
    return res
    
result = pd.DataFrame(getDescendants('node0', '', 0), columns=['node', 'parent', 'level'])
print(result)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: avoid screenshots, also provide minimal reprodicable code

Answer (score 0):

A tree-like data structure can be represented as a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) for which we can use the [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/digraph.html) library. This allows to build the graph step by step while iterating through the rows of the dataframe. Sibling information can be stored in separate DAGs which are then used to retrieve the siblings in the correct order.

The following is an example script:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.dag import dag_longest_path, dag_longest_path_length


_ = None
data = [
    [0, _, _],
    [1, _, 2],
    [2, _, 0],
    [3, 2, _],
    [4, 1, 7],
    [5, 2, 6],
    [6, 2, 3],
    [7, 1, _],
    [8, 6, _],
]


G = nx.DiGraph()  # main graph (tree)
S = defaultdict(nx.DiGraph)  # graphs for siblings

for n, p, s in data:
    if p is None:
        G.add_node(n)
    else:
        G.add_edge(p, n)
    if s is None:
        S[p].add_node(n)
    else:
        S[p].add_edge(s, n)


class empty:  # utility for printing the resulting tree
    def __repr__(self): return ' '
empty = empty()


n_cols = 1 + dag_longest_path_length(G)
result = [[empty]*n_cols for _ in data]


def fill(node, row, col):
    """Fill the resulting table at position (row, col) and return number of rows used."""
    result[row][col] = node
    count = 1
    for child in dag_longest_path(S[node]):  # there is only one path
        count += fill(child, row+count, col+1)
    return count


row = 0
for node in sorted({n for n,d in G.in_degree() if d == 0}):
    row += fill(node, row, 0)


from pprint import pprint 

pprint(result)
```

This is the output:

```py
[[0,  ,  ],
 [1,  ,  ],
 [ , 7,  ],
 [ , 4,  ],
 [2,  ,  ],
 [ , 3,  ],
 [ , 6,  ],
 [ ,  , 8],
 [ , 5,  ]]
```